# Explain output of this C program

Tags: c, initialization

Found this code at [C Puzzles](http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/index.php):

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
  int a=1;
  switch(a)
  {   int b=20;
      case 1: printf("b is %d\n",b);
              break;
      default:printf("b is %d\n",b);
              break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
b is 51
```

I can't seem to understand this output.

Comment: You do realize that the point of 'C puzzles' is for you to figure this out?

Comment: Replace the switch with the `goto`s it represents, and you'll see why.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yes I do, it's been a hour and I got nothing, so I gave up..

Comment: Inside switch nothing will be accepted like asigning and printf except inside case.

Comment: Even if question is about Undefined behavior but its interesting to know about this code, if its not a duplicate with other questions. Question deserves Up-votes not down-votes, +1 to this question. Down-voters should mark duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using a variable with an indeterminate value (<s>invoking undefined behaviour</s>) by jumping past the initialization of the variable `b`.  The program can produce any value and it will be correct.

The C standard even covers this case (in a non-normative example).

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.8.4.2 The `switch` statement:
>
> 7 EXAMPLE In the artificial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
>         int i = 4;
>         f(i);
>     case 0:
>         i = 17;
>         /* falls through into default code */
>     default:
>         printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is never
>   initialized, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the printf function will
>   access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the call to the function `f` cannot be reached.

Note the 'indeterminate value' comment.

---

<sup>There is some room for discussion about whether accessing an indeterminate value leads to undefined behaviour.  Under some circumstances (trap representations), it can lead to undefined behaviour.  It will take me some time to determine whether 'possibly undefined behaviour' should be considered 'undefined behaviour'. Accessing an uninitialized variable is a bad idea, and there is nothing you can say about the value that is printed in your code.</sup>

Comment: every time same output?

Comment: Undefined behavior can do what it wants, including giving you the same output every time.

Comment: Imagine it going to 20 when someone tries it. Some big confusion will come from that hehe.

Comment: “Indeterminate value” is not the same as undefined behavior. The behavior is only undefined in this case because of C 2011 (n1570) 6.3.2.1 2. (If, for example, the code evaluated `&b` (but never used the resulting value), there would not be any undefined behavior unless the indeterminate value happened to be a trap representation.) So I suggest the answer explain why this is technically undefined behavior, although, on most C implementations, it results only in an indeterminate value being used.

Comment: Although the standard is undefined it might be pseudo defined by the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is not being initialized.  Put it outside of the switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    switch(a) {   
        int b=20;
        printf("This gets called!\n");
        case 1: 
                printf("b is %d\n",b);
                break;
        default:
                printf("b is %d\n",b);
                break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The key here is that `int b=20;` never gets called. The compiler will create the variable `b` but it never gets initialised.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `switch statement` nothing will be accepted like `assigning values to the variable`  and `printing except inside case`. if you want the b value assign it outside the switch . Also b value should be like garbage value it can't change until assign some values to the particular location.