# declaring variables outside case

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have declared a variable outside a case statement. But if I print its value in a case, it says 0. Can anyone explain?

The confusion is ***why is the declaration part is taken***(int b, else, compilation error for undefined variable) and ***why not initialisation?***

*I was **unable to get an answer with questions marked duplicates**, hence the post.*

```
    main() 
    { 
        int a=1; 
        switch(a) 
        {    

            int b = 6;
            case 1: 
            {
            printf("b is %d\n",b); 
        }
            break; 
            default:printf("b is %d in default\n",a); 
            break; 
        } 
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: this is Undefined behavior

Comment: [Explain output of this C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749100/explain-output-of-this-c-program)

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this..?

Answer (score 1):

variable init can be translated to

```
int b;
b = 6;
```

The case acts like a goto which is skipped to when the switch is encountered. Therefore, you jump over the line `b = 6` straight to the `printf`, which makes the value of `b` undefined.

Comment: why is int b; not skipped in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the `case` statement as a goto.

```
switch(test){
  printf("This code is skipped!\n");

  case 1:
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

When the variable is tested, you jump to the matching case ignoring anything between the `switch` and the `case`. In your example, the variable definition was skipped entirely.

You are printing the value of an uninitialized variable.